# gnuplot: How to make an error bar graph with multiple files

Tags: gnuplot

I'm stuggling to make a graph with gnuplot using error bars.
I have multiple text files for each value.

For exemple, file *100.txt* which contains values for x = 100 looks like this

```
0.000509004
0.000467744
0.000480521
0.000468907
0.000481908
...
```

I've tried multiple things, including the more straightforward stuffs like

```
plot "100.txt" using $1 with yerrorbars, \
"200.txt" using $1 with yerrorbars, \
...
```

but it just doesn't work.

I have the feeling that I'm missing something simple, yet I can put my finger on it.

Comment: What do you want your plot to look like? Do you want one y point per x value (file), with error bars based on the statistics of the numbers in that file? In that case it would be best to preprocess the data with another tool and create a data file with lines of the form `xvalue yvalue yerror` and plot with `plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:3 with yerrorbars`.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but I thought gnuplot was capable of processing the data itself and generate error bars.

Comment: To my knowledge gnuplot cannot generate error bars point-by-point, only statistics for an entire data set. So again I recommend preprocessing the data using another utility (python, etc.) or possibly in the program you have that generates the .txt files in the first place.